# Detect all changes (made by the user) to the text in controls on the form

Tags: java, swing, controls, event-handling

I have a program with a Save() method that saves all data in spinners and textfields on the form. Is there a way to call "Save()" every time the user makes a change to a textfield or spinner? Something similar to a generic event handler.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook up a single instance of [ChangeListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeListener.html) to all your controls, which could look like (when an inner class):

```
private class ListenerImpl implements ChangeListener {
   public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) { save(); }
}
```

to add this listener in one go you can loop over the children of your `Container` like this:

```
final ListenerImpl l = new ListenerImpl();
for (Component c : getComponents()) {
   if (c instanceof JSpinner) {
      ((JSpinner)c).addChangeListener(l);
   } else if (c instanceof JTextPane ) { } // ... other types of components
}
```

you have to look for the different types of components because there is no interface which defines the `addChangeListener(..)` method (that I am aware of).

Comment: Good, but is there any way of doing it in a for each loop to go through all of the textifleds and spinners instead of adding each one manually? I have about 15 of each and the code is going to get very long if I do that.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you add a `ChangeListener` or a `FocusListener` to each of the controls in the form and call `Save()` in one of the call-back methods. (Actually, I would probably go for the `FocusListener` and call `Save()` from the `focusLost`-method.)

- [How to Write a Focus Listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html)

Comment: Is there a way of using a for each loop to go through every spinner on the form? (So I can add a focus listener to each one in the loop instead of doing it manually).

Comment: for (Component c:getComponents()) if (c instanceof Spinner) { ((Spinner)c).addChangeListener(listener);}

Comment: Yes this is possible (not sure it is "best practice" though). You can loop through the components by using [`Container.getComponents()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents%28%29). Something like this: `for (Component comp: form.getComponents()) if (comp instanceof JSpinner) comp.addFocusListener(yourListener);` (or `addChangeListener()` if you prefer that.

Comment: Thanks :) I would +1 you, but I still need 15 rep to do that :/